# Unit Test issues with Entity FrameWork (nullable values)

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, unit-testing

im trying to implement a uniTest for my application so when i tried to get User by ID value in my application it's work fine, but when i tried to do the same scenario from my unit test class i always get nullable result even if the ID value is correct :

```
Class AccountController : ApiController
{ 
    private UserService _UserService = null;

    public AccountController()
    {
        _UserService = new UserService();
    }

   [AllowAnonymous]
   [Route("test")]
   public IHttpActionResult test()
    {
       var user = _UserService.getUserById(1); //user --> not null;
    }
}
```

but when i tried a UnitTest Script

```
     [TestClass]
        public class userServiceTest
        {
            private UserService _UserService = null;

            public userServiceTest()
            {
                _UserService = new UserService();
            }
     [TestMethod]
        public void checkUserCase1()
            {
             var user = _UserService.getUserById(1); //user is null value !!!;
            }
}
```

User Service :

```
    public class UserService 
    {

        private GenericRepository<User> _UserRepository = null;

        public UserService()
        {
            _UserRepository = new GenericRepository<User>();
        }

        public User getUserById(int id)
        {
            return _UserRepository.Find(x => x.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
        }

   }
```

The Generic Repository

```
 public class GenericRepository<T> : IGenericRepository<T> where T : class
    {
        private MyDbContext db = null;
        private DbSet<T> table = null;

        public IEnumerable<T> Find(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
        {
            return table.Where(predicate);
        }

    }
```

IGeneric :

```
public interface IGenericRepository<T> where T : class
    {
        IEnumerable<T> SelectAll();
        T SelectByID(object id);
        void Insert(T obj);
        void Update(T obj);
        void Delete(object id);
        void Save();
        IEnumerable<T> Find(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);
    }
```

My DB Context :

```
 public class MyDbContext : DbContext
    {

        public MyDbContext()
            : base("AuthWebApiDb")
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<MyDbContext>(new MyDbInitializer());
        }

        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

    }
```

I have Two Project : One is the simple project, the second is the Unit Test

Comment: We'd need to see the `UserService.getUserById()` code

Comment: Could we see the `GenericRepository<>` code too? We need to see all the way down to where you access the entity framework model. Are you trying to access your live database from inside the unit test? (in which case are all the connection strings in the config file for the unit test project?)

Comment: I just modified my post (no the database access is from outside a UniTest Project)

Comment: Looks like you are never accessing the database here? the `UserService` initialises a new `GenericRepository<User>` but nowhere do you pass the generic repository your db context? The `table` and `db` fields are both null and are never set to any real value, no? I have a hunch your main project has a db connection string in it's config and unit test project not but I can't even see how your `MyDbContext` class is instantiated ANYwhere in the above code. What am I missing?

Comment: yeah is that what im thinking too, the uniTest project doesn't have the access to the database, but it's not logical because  when i instantiate the user service , the user serve constructor create a MyContextDb object so the unitTest project should have a connection to the databse !!

Comment: So what you thing is that any chance to make the uniTestr project work Fine ?

Comment: In all honesty I don't know whats going on here. With only the code above I cannot see how your AccountController could possibly be accessing the db either! Incidentally, as a general rule you'd be advised to not access the db in your controller test (instead you'd use dependency injection, test doubles, etc. but that is firmly beyond the scope of a possible answer - or comment). With that said, it's certainly POSSIBLE to access a db from a unit test project - you just need to make sure you have EF installed there and the connection strings in the app.config file in the test project

Comment: Thank' Men it's worked fine Now i add the connection string into my app.config File, you are the best :D

Answer (score 0):

- Check if EF is innstalled  in your UnitTest project.
- Put the connection string in the app.config file in the unitest project.
  **Thank's @Stewart_T**